# Using rvest to scrape a table from a website

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I wrote this code and it used to work, but I think the site changed the class and I'm failing to scrape the table now.

```
library(rvest)
url <- read_html("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=AAPL")
tables <- html_nodes(url,"table")
scraped <- tables %>% html_nodes("table") %>% .[6] %>% 
  html_table(fill=TRUE) %>% data.frame()
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which table(s) do you want to scrape? Can you perhaps post an image showing that?

Comment: SRYY the data have index,market cup ,Income,Sales.... all the table here

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

```
library(rvest)
url <- read_html("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=AAPL")
scraped <- html_nodes(url,"table.snapshot-table2") %>%
  html_table(fill=TRUE) %>% data.frame()

str(scraped)
'data.frame':   12 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ X1 : chr  "Index" "Market Cap" "Income" "Sales" ...
 $ X2 : chr  "DJIA S&P500" "2076.44B" "57.41B" "274.52B" ...
 $ X3 : chr  "P/E" "Forward P/E" "PEG" "P/S" ...
 $ X4 : chr  "37.56" "28.41" "2.97" "7.56" ...
 $ X5 : chr  "EPS (ttm)" "EPS next Y" "EPS next Q" "EPS this Y" ...
 $ X6 : chr  "3.27" "4.32" "1.39" "10.20%" ...
 $ X7 : chr  "Insider Own" "Insider Trans" "Inst Own" "Inst Trans" ...
 $ X8 : chr  "0.07%" "-6.91%" "59.80%" "-" ...
 $ X9 : chr  "Shs Outstand" "Shs Float" "Short Float" "Short Ratio" ...
 $ X10: chr  "17.06B" "16.99B" "0.52%" "0.61" ...
 $ X11: chr  "Perf Week" "Perf Month" "Perf Quarter" "Perf Half Y" ...
 $ X12: chr  "7.79%" "12.73%" "-8.54%" "50.98%" ...
```

Comment: perfect thxx i try all this hour .snapshot-table2 :X not add table :X

Comment: @Chani consider marking the question as answered.